# Set value of one multidimensional list to value of another multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional list in Python 3.9 which contains several Strings. Now I want `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]` to be `[["d", "a"], ["b", "c"]]`. So every String move up one place. Here is the code I have tried:

```
list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
helper = list
list[0][0] = helper[1][1]
list[0][1] = helper[0][0]
list[1][0] = helper[0][1]
list[1][1] = helper[1][0]
print(list)
```

But unfortunately, the code gives me `[['d', 'd'], ['d', 'd']]` instead of `[["d", "a"], ["b", "c"]]`. Printing out `helper` at the end of my program gives me `[['d', 'd'], ['d', 'd']]` as well, but why? Shouldn't the helper be `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]` because I set him to `list` at the top of my program.

```
list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
helper = list
```

However, the following code proves that helper is changing during my program:

```
list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
helper = list
print("Top of program:", helper)
list[0][0] = helper[1][1]
list[0][1] = helper[0][0]
list[1][0] = helper[0][1]
list[1][1] = helper[1][0]
print("Bottom of program:", helper)
```

Output:

```
Top of program: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
Bottom of program: [['d', 'd'], ['d', 'd']]
```

So my question is why `helper` changes its values and why my program doesn't do what it should do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: `helper` is a *reference* to `list`, so any changes to `list` change `helper` as well.

Comment: Initialize `helper` as a deep copy of list: `helper = [sub[:] for sub in list]`

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. When you put your answer as a "real" answer I can mark it as "accepted"

Comment: Also I would discourage you from using list as name for your list, as it is already a predefined function, that will be overwritten by your definition